# Do any automated conversion tools exist for porting C++ code to 64-bit?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I'm researching methods to port a large (>10M lines) amount of C++ code to 64-bit. I have looked at static code analyzers and compiler flags, and I am now looking at macros or other tools that can make common, repetitive changes.

I've written a few regular expressions to see how well they work in practice, and as predicted, they're quite effective. That said, it takes a while to build the expressions in the first place, so I'd like to see if there are any lists of such expressions or software tools that can perform changes automatically.

The following lines are prototypical examples of code to be matched and fixed. (To clarify, these lines are not meant to represent a single block of code, but instead are lines pulled from different places.)

```
int i = 0;
long objcount;
int count = channels.count(ch);
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) { /*...*/ }
```

The objective is not to thoroughly port code to 64-bit, but instead to perform a first pass over the code to reduce the amount of code that needs to be manually inspected. It's okay for some needed changes to be missed, and it's *probably* okay for some wrong changes to be made, but those should be minimized.

Visual Studio is the IDE that will be used for conversion work, so something that works well with VS is a plus. Cost is not an issue.

Comment: In what sense do those lines need to be fixed?

Comment: @Oli: The example does not show it but `int count` may be too small to hold the `size_t` return of `channels.count`. In the for loop, `int k` may wrap before ever reaching the size of `long n`. Etc.

Comment: In all cases, the declared `int` or `long` needs to be changed to the memsize type `size_t`. This isn't necessarily true of every instance in every application, but in all cases I've seen so far in actual code, it's either necessary or does no harm.

Comment: @Henry why was int Ok in 32-bit but not in 64-bit?

Comment: In the code I've ported (which was admittedly written with a possible port to 64 bit in mind), all the problems were highlighted by the compiler as warnings. The fix wasn't always to promote to size_t; in some cases casts (or runtime checks) needed to be added to make it clear that 32 bits was appropriate.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, if the variable is storing something like the offset of a character in a string or the index of an object in a data structure, an `int` (typically 32 bits wide) is sufficient because there cannot be enough elements to overflow the value. On a 64-bit system, something like an array can easily exceed the limit imposed by `int`. (I suppose that `int`, being signed, could also cause problems on a 32-bit machine, but some 32-bit operating systems limit process memory to 2GB anyway.)

Comment: @Henry: I doubt you'll be able to find such a tool, because *correct* code works just fine when you port it. And the thing about incorrect code is that it doesn't obey any rules, so it's kind of hard for an automated tool to deal with.

Comment: @Alan Stokes, indeed. There are certainly instances where I'll need to fix something at 32 bits, instead. My goal is to construct or use some kind of system do make a best attempt and then handle those cases individually.

Comment: @Henry: why on Earth would your arrays suddenly grow that large just because you port your software to 64-bit?

Comment: @jalf, because the program can now work with data sets that large. It's currently capped because of the 32-bit memory ceiling.

Comment: @Henry If your program has the same inputs, it will work the same way on both platforms. If it is broken on one it is broken on the other. In any case, changing things to size_t won't solve anything.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, once the program is running on 64-bit, it will have larger inputs. This is that rare case where an application has actually run up against the 32-bit memory limit in a big way, and so compromises have been made to fit the running program in a small space of memory. Those compromises will be reversed when the memory limit is lifted.

Comment: @Henry where will it get those larger inputs from?

Comment: I am working on a similar project. I used the errors and warnings from the compiler first and then the warnings from a static analyzer tool. there were lots of places to check (and fix), but I didn't trust making the changes automatically. I preferred doing it the hard way and manually inspect every flagged line. and there were many cases when it proved the right decision, because the context was rather complex for a tool to make automatic changes

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, other parts of code will be (manually) updated to generate larger inputs (like in-memory caches). Nothing about compiling for x64 will magically push the size of the inputs above four billion items. Since the program will be able to break the 2-3GB ceiling, we'll make performance improvements that increase memory consumption instead of only working with optimizations.

Comment: @Marius Bancila, I'd be loathe to release code that's been touched by an automatic tool and never reviewed, but code review is probably faster than manually inspecting and applying each change. That said, I would certainly prefer a more conservative tool. The idea is to reduce the workload (and therefore cost) of performing the port, not to automate the entire process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rexexps suffer from a high false positive rate; by definition, a "regular expression" cannot parse a context free langauge such as C++.  Futhermore, regexps cannot take into
account type information; is

```
   fooT i=0;
```

ok, for some typedef'd fooT?  Finally, a regexp cannot change code; you might consider Perl or SED (using regexps to drive changes), but you'll get erroneous changes due to the false positives of regexps.  At 10M SLOC, that can't be fun; a 5% error rate means possibly 50,000 lines of code to fix by hand.

You might consider a [program transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation) tool.  Such engines operate on language structures, not text, and more sophisticated versions know scopes, types, and the meaning of symbol (e.g., what is fooT, exactly?).   They offer you the ability to write langauge- and context-specific patterns, and propose structurally correct code changes, using the surface syntax of the target language.  This enables the reliable application of code changes on scale.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [C++ Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html) has been used to carry out massive changes to large C++ systems in a syntax- and type-accurate way.  (See Akers, R., Baxter, I., Mehlich, M. , Ellis, B. , Luecke, K., Case Study: Re-engineering C++ Component Models Via Automatic Program Transformation, Information & Software Technology 49(3):275-291 2007.)

Comment: My goal in using automation is to reduce the amount of code that needs to be manually inspected, not to solve every problem. Yes, a regular expression may turn up false positives, and it definitely won't catch everything, but the ideal expressions for the job are inherently conservative. Your toolkit looks interesting, but how can it help aside from being "smarter" than a regular expression? (In other words, can it perform any other restructuring than identifying expressions and changing them according to some rule? How much will it do for a 64-bit conversion project?)

Comment: @Henry: The argument over false positives is how many you can tolerate. A truly conservative detector says everything needs attention but its a complete waste of your time.  What you want is the tightest, conservative detector you can get, and real parsing with name resolution is needed to do that.  I'm surprised my example about fooT isn't convincing; no regular expression can help you with except to conservatively, always say "might be wrong".   ...

Comment: @Henry: ... that said, the value in a tool like DMS is that not only can it detect that you might have an issue, but it can actually make changes to the code. You can even make such changes experimentally (since you can always run a revised version of the tool again on the original sources). So you get better detection, fewer false positives, and (some) automated changes. What's not to like, compared to regexps?  10M lines is a pretty big pile of code.

Comment: I'll agree that it can offer better detection and even better changes than regular expressions (though I must point out that regex _can_ modify code). Regex is free, though, and support is built into Visual Studio (albeit with an obnoxious regex syntax). I don't doubt that DMS is a powerful tool, I'm just not sure about cost versus benefit. For starters, which packages would I need to work with both ANSI and VC++6 code? Has DMS been used to assist 64-bit conversion before?

Comment: @Henry: You are welcome to type regexps into VS to your heart's content (and how responsive is it when you have 10M SLOC?) I just don't believe you have the heart to do this for 10M SLOC and all the issues you may find.   For DMS, you'd only need the VC++6 front end; AFAIK, it includes ANSI completely.   DMS has not been used for 64 bit conversion before; it has been used to automate architectual restructuring of large-scale C++ source codes.

Answer (score 0):

What version of the compiler are you using? Did you try running the compiler with the /Wp64 flag to detect portability to 64 bit issues?

From the MS website:
"/Wp64 detects 64-bit portability problems on types that are also marked with the __w64 keyword. /Wp64 is off by default in the Visual C++ 32-bit compiler and on by default in the Visual C++ 64-bit compiler."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt4xw8fh%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the `/Wp64` flag. It's helpful, but it produces far too many warnings to individually inspect each one across the entire codebase.

Comment: That flag is deprecated now. You get much more accurate diagnostics by just running the compiler with a 64 bit target. (Which you can do even on a 32 bit platform.)

Comment: that flag was introduced in VS2005 to "prepare" you for writing code for the 64-bit platforms. but in VS2008 it was deemed obsolete, and you should build directly using x64/IA64 as the target platform.